# HTTP 502 error when perfoming a rolling update of a backend

Tags: traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I am using traefik version `1.7.7` as an ingress controller in a kubernetes cluster version `1.11.5`.

Each time I perform a rolling upgrade of a Deployment of one of my backend, Traefik generates a 502 error (mostly only one) with the following error when I set Traefik in debug mode.

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: read tcp 172.21.51.209:56624-\u003e172.21.63.132:3000: read: connection reset by peer","time":"2019-01-17T14:32:37Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"vulcand/oxy/forward/http: Round trip: http://172.21.63.132:3000, code: 502, Length: 11, duration: 623.180762ms","time":"2019-01-17T14:32:37Z"}
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid those 502?

Comment: ```readinessProbe:exec:
    command: ["./checks.sh", "/tmp/gunicorn.pid"]
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  failureThreshold: 2
  timeoutSeconds: 5```